# Can I run Eclipse che on a small VPS?

Tags: django, eclipse, web-development-server, eclipse-che

I have a relatively small VPS that I use as a remote dev environment :

- 1 vCore
- 2 Mb of RAM

I plan to have up to 3 dev environments on the VPS. I dont need to run 2 simultaneously however.

The biggest project is roughly the same size as a small Magento eShop. It is actually run by Python and Django.

The environment runs on Ubuntu + Nginx + uWCGI but this could be changed.

I can code remotely in the VPS using Eclipse RSE or Codeanywhere.

However Eclipse CHE offer very interesting functionalities for this type of remote environment.

The main risk is that the VPS configuration is very small. It is exactly the minimal configuration stated in the doc. I don't know if I can use it this way without making things really slow...

Answer (score 0):

My instinct is "no", I think 2MB of RAM is not sufficient given that the Che workspace server is itself a Java application that needs about 750 MB of RAM. If you are running the workspace somewhere else, and just using the VPS as a compute node for container workspaces, I would suspect the answer is still no, as your container OS and language runtime will need more than 2MB of RAM. If you meant 2GB of RAM, it's still difficult, but maybe feasible, to run a workspace with a full Django environment on there, using a workspace server running on a separate host.

It sure would be nice to see if you can make it work, though - and I would love to hear if you make it work!